# Loading svg external link source in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am not an expert when using svg-s , but so far i haven't had kind of problem with loading svg in React app. I am getting svg from external link source and would like to use it with `svg` tag and not with just `image` tag, because with image tag there are another problems with sizing.
Problem is that SVG doesn't show in the browser. this is my svg code`

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <use linkHref="https://restcountries.eu/data/rus.svg" className="country__flag" width='300' height='100'></use>
</svg>
```

There are no errors in the console . Svg exists in DOM but it doesnt show . I want to import it at runtime . App is about searching countries and getting their flags , so when user searches for certain country , i make request from my server and then send it to client . 
Should i add some test rules for svg in webpack ?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Do you want to import it at build time or at runtime?

Comment: No errors in the console . Svg exists in DOM but it doesnt show . I want to import it at runtime . App is about searching countries and getting their flags , so when user searches for certain country , i make request from my server and then send it to client .

Comment: this is the link to website `
[Countries](https://react-countries.herokuapp.com)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<embed className='yourClassForCss' src="https://restcountries.eu/data/rus.svg">
```

if this is link to your website then make sure that it is static folder(that handle svg).

You dont need rules in webpack if this is other website's url

Comment: It's just an API , which provides information about countries.

Comment: @Norayr Ghukasyan you can try this.

Comment: You mean `<svg><embed className='yourClassForCss' src="https://restcountries.eu/data/rus.svg"></svg>`  ?

Comment: @Norayr Ghukasyan only `<embed className='yourClassForCss' src="https://restcountries.eu/data/rus.svg">`

Comment: I tried with `embed` . That works , but the size of flag is very big , and when  i tried to give it specific sizes like this `<embed src={el.flag} className="country__flag" width='200' height='100' alt='country flag'/>` , it shows just the top part of image (like it just crops the image) . For example if my flag has the colors `red,blue,orange` , it showed me just the red color .

Comment: @Norayr Ghukasyan I think you got solution for this question and for your next question i tried this and your image render properly might be because of css **className="country__flag"** you can try without clasName , or Upload that class code so we can check.

Comment: I tried everything but couldnt manage to fix it . Anyway , thanks a lot for help